# case-insensitive uniqueness constraints in Persistent?

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent, esqueleto

This is probably a stupid question and I'm somehow overlooking existing content with sub-par Google-fu skills, but is there a way to create a new Text field using Persistent, with a uniqueness constraint on that field, whereby uniqueness is case-insensitive? For example, say I want to create a Username field that is unique with no duplicates so that four different users cannot create the Satan, SATAN, satan, and SaTaN username records?

Or would I have to lean on Postgres-specific features and use raw SQL to achieve this? Or is it perhaps accomplished in esqueleto without using raw SQL?

**Update 1:**
I tried addiing @MaxGabriel's revision as `src/ModelTypes.hs` in a newly **scaffolded** Yesod site & importing it in `src/Model.hs`. To this I seemed to have to add `import Database.Persist.Sql` to get rid of one compiler error, now I get this error 3 times while running `yesod devel`:

```
Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Text’
Perhaps you meant ‘T.Text’ (imported from Data.Text)
```

Haven't yet updated the scaffodled User model (used by the dummy authentication) in `config/models.persistentmodels`to use the new `Username` type ...

```
User
    ident Text
    password Text Maybe
    UniqueUser ident
    deriving Typeable
```

... but on previous attempts to simply change `ident` to use `citext`, it would work for inserting a new record into the db, but then seemed to balk at retrieving and converting the type of that record when trying to authenticate a user.

**Update 2:**
Output after adding `import Data.Text (Text)` to `ModelTypes.hs`

```
>>> stack exec -- yesod devel                                                                                            
Yesod devel server. Enter 'quit' or hit Ctrl-C to quit.
Application can be accessed at:

http://localhost:3000
https://localhost:3443
If you wish to test https capabilities, you should set the following variable:
  export APPROOT=https://localhost:3443

uniqueci> configure (lib)
Configuring uniqueci-0.0.0...
uniqueci> build (lib)
Preprocessing library for uniqueci-0.0.0..
Building library for uniqueci-0.0.0..
[ 4 of 13] Compiling ModelTypes

/zd/pj/yesod/uniqueci/src/ModelTypes.hs:16:10: error:
    • Illegal instance declaration for ‘PersistField (CI Text)’
        (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
         where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
         and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
         Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
    • In the instance declaration for ‘PersistField (CI Text)’
   |
16 | instance PersistField (CI Text) where
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/zd/pj/yesod/uniqueci/src/ModelTypes.hs:21:10: error:
    • Illegal instance declaration for ‘PersistFieldSql (CI Text)’
        (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
         where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
         and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
         Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
    • In the instance declaration for ‘PersistFieldSql (CI Text)’
   |
21 | instance PersistFieldSql (CI Text) where
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

--  While building package uniqueci-0.0.0 using:
      /zd/hngnr/.stack_sym_ngnr/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_3.0.1.0_ghc-8.8.4 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-3.0.1.0 build lib:uniqueci --ghc-options ""
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Type help for available commands. Press enter to force a rebuild.
```

**Update 3:**

After adding `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}` to `ModelType.hs`, the above error goes away. Upon trying to use the new `Username` type in the scaffolded `User` model like so

```
-- config/models.persistentmodels

User
    ident Username        -- default is ident Text
    password Text Maybe
    UniqueUser ident
    deriving Typeable
Email
    email Text
    userId UserId Maybe
    verkey Text Maybe
    UniqueEmail email
Comment json -- Adding "json" causes ToJSON and FromJSON instances to be derived.
    message Text
    userId UserId Maybe
    deriving Eq
    deriving Show
```

a new error occurred:

```
[ 2 of 13] Compiling Model [config/models.persistentmodels changed]
[ 7 of 13] Compiling Foundation

/zd/pj/yesod/uniqueci/src/Foundation.hs:251:35: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘ModelTypes.Username’
                  with actual type ‘Text’
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘credsIdent creds’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘UniqueUser $ credsIdent creds’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        x <- getBy $ UniqueUser $ credsIdent creds
    |
251 |         x <- getBy $ UniqueUser $ credsIdent creds
    |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/zd/pj/yesod/uniqueci/src/Foundation.hs:255:31: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘ModelTypes.Username’
                  with actual type ‘Text’
    • In the ‘userIdent’ field of a record
      In the first argument of ‘insert’, namely
        ‘User {userIdent = credsIdent creds, userPassword = Nothing}’
      In the second argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely
        ‘insert
           User {userIdent = credsIdent creds, userPassword = Nothing}’
    |
255 |                 { userIdent = credsIdent creds
    |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: The best way to do this is definitely with a [`citext`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/citext.html) column. I have no idea how to do that from Persistent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible. Taking Carl's comment from above of using the [citext](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/citext.html) column type for case-insensitive character string type, you can use something like this.

First, add PersistField and PersistFieldSql instances for `CI Text`, which is case-insensitive `Text`. This must be done in a separate file from where you declare your Persistent models with Template Haskell. In this file, you can add a newtype for `Username`, or you can use `CI Text` directly in your Persistent models. I recommend the newtype approach for readability.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

module ModelTypes where

import Database.Persist
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.Encoding as TE
-- Add the case-insensitive package for this:
import Data.CaseInsensitive (CI)
import qualified Data.CaseInsensitive as CI

instance PersistField (CI Text) where
  toPersistValue ciText = PersistDbSpecific $ TE.encodeUtf8 (CI.original ciText)
  fromPersistValue (PersistDbSpecific bs) = Right $ CI.mk (TE.decodeUtf8 bs)
  fromPersistValue x = Left . T.pack $ "When Expected PersistDbSpecific, received: " ++ show x

instance PersistFieldSql (CI Text) where
  sqlType _ = SqlOther "citext"

newtype Username = Username {unUsername :: CI Text}
  deriving stock (Show)
  deriving newtype (Eq, Ord, PersistField, PersistFieldSql)
```

Then, import that file into the file that loads your Persistent models with Template Haskell:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
     --resolver lts-15
     --install-ghc
     runghc
     --package persistent
     --package persistent-postgresql
     --package persistent-template
     --package network
     --package mtl
-}


{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import Control.Monad.Logger (runStderrLoggingT)
import Database.Persist
import Database.Persist.Postgresql
import Database.Persist.TH
import ModelTypes

share
  [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"]
  [persistLowerCase|
Person
    name Username
    UniqueName name
    deriving Show
|]

connStr = "host=localhost dbname=test user=postgres password=postgres port=5433"

main :: IO ()
main =
  runStderrLoggingT $
  withPostgresqlPool connStr 10 $
  \pool ->
     liftIO $
     do flip runSqlPersistMPool pool $
          do runMigration migrateAll
             johnId <- insert $ Person (Username "John Doe")
             liftIO $ print johnId
             return ()
```

But note that before executing the code, you need to create the extension for the database:

```
test=# \c test
test=# CREATE EXTENSION citext;
CREATE EXTENSION
```

And then you can execute the code:

```
$ stack postgres.hs
Migrating: CREATe TABLE "person"("id" SERIAL8  PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,"name" citext NOT NULL)
[Debug#SQL] CREATe TABLE "person"("id" SERIAL8  PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,"name" citext NOT NULL); []
Migrating: ALTER TABLE "person" ADD CONSTRAINT "unique_name" UNIQUE("name")
[Debug#SQL] ALTER TABLE "person" ADD CONSTRAINT "unique_name" UNIQUE("name"); []
[Debug#SQL] INSERT INTO "person"("name") VALUES(?) RETURNING "id"; [PersistText "John Doe"]
SqlBackendKey {unSqlBackendKey = 1}
```

And you can then go and actually inspect the database to confirm that `citext` column is indeed created:

```
test=# \d person;
                            Table "public.person"
 Column |  Type  | Collation | Nullable |              Default
--------+--------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
 id     | bigint |           | not null | nextval('person_id_seq'::regclass)
 name   | citext |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "person_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "unique_name" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (name)
```

Comment: I recommended adding the `case-insensitive` Haskell package make a newtype like `newtype Username = CI Text`. Give this a PersistFieldSql instance with SQL type "citext". This means both your Haskell and database representation of usernames are case-insensitive.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point and would be better IMO. I will try to see if I can update the answer, free feel to edit the answer or add a new answer!

Comment: Ok, updated your answer to use `case-insensitive`. Tell me if that looks good!

Comment: I updated my question after trying to use @MaxGabriel revision

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't compile this code so it probably has little missing imports like that. @derrgill give it a try now

Comment: I updated the post with the output after adding your edits @MaxGabriel

Comment: @derrgill Ah it was missing the FlexibleInstance language extension, which I added to the edit. The error messages the compiler is giving there are pretty good about what to fix there, if you can try to use those

Comment: @MaxGabriel Sorry I didn't realize that, thanks for your help. I got rid of that error using your edit, but when I try using the new type in the authentication system, it gives me a new error that I don't know how to resolve (I've amended the post again). Even if I got that to work, I suppose it will only fix the "dummy" auth system, not real username, password combo system, so this is probably just a waste of time for you.

Comment: Hey @derrgill, nice job. The remaining compiler errors are because you're no longer using Text, you're using a Username. `credsIdent` is returning `Text`, so you'll need a `Text -> Username` function. This should be something like `Username $ CI.mk $ credsIdent creds` (You'll need to import the ModelTypes file and CaseInsensitive as CI)